# Github WebHooks and ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

In order to use WebHook URLs in Github, do I need to be logged into my web server using ssh? I cannot seem to get WebHooks to work and I thought maybe this would be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. This is what Github has to say regarding Webhooks.

> We’ll hit these URLs with POST requests when you push to us, passing
>   along information about the push.

Maybe you are not processing the JSON received from Github properly. To test, you can just create a temporary bin on [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/), add this as the Webhook URL on your Github repo, and hit the `Test Hook` button.

Answer (score 0):

I've found little tools to help deploy your code from Github or Gitlab so I created Deepl.io to handle Web-Hooks and call scripts to deploy on your own server.
This handles the JSON that's sent from github or gitlab and uses your own script to react. You can use your own PHP or shell scripts after receiving the pull notification...
Check it out: http://deepl.io